# Robocopy error in Visual Studio 2010 ported project

Tags: visual-studio-2010, build-process

I've ported a C++ project from VS 2005 to 2010.  When it compiles it gives the error below when using rc (robocopy) to copy project outputs.  I can't find any place to configure switches for this process.  How do I can the flag to prevent the error?

Thanks,
Gerry

Generating Code...

```
1>  
1>  -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1>     ROBOCOPY     ::     Robust File Copy for Windows     ::     Version XP026
1>  -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1>  
1>    Started : Tue Mar 01 14:25:00 2011
1>  
1>     Source - 
1>       Dest - 
1>  
1>      Files : 
1>    Options : /COPY:DAT /R:1 /W:1 
1>  
1>  ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1>  
1>RC : error : Invalid Parameter #1 : "/D"
1>  
1>         Simple Usage :: ROBOCOPY source destination /MIR
1>  
1>               source :: Source Directory (drive:\path or \\server\share\path).
1>          destination :: Destination Dir  (drive:\path or \\server\share\path).
1>                 /MIR :: Mirror a complete directory tree.
1>  
1>      For more usage information run ROBOCOPY /? or read Robocopy.Doc.
1>  
1>  NOTE: Read "True Replication" in Robocopy.Doc prior to first use of /MIR !
1>  ****  /MIR can DELETE files as well as copy them !
```

Answer (score 0):

Try looking in the project properties, Build Events, Post-build event.

Comment: Nice try, but I don't have any post build events.  I think the error occurs when copying obj files before the link.

Comment: @Gerry: how about opening the .vcxproj file with notepad and searching for robocopy?

Comment: I went ahead and created a new 2010 project.  I ported the compile and link flags from my old project.